# Change datatype of Realm field - Java

Tags: android, realm

I would like to change the data type of a Realm field from `String` to `int` and FYI the field is also a `Primary Key`. I couldn't find a method in `RealmMigration` to solve this issue.

PS : My app is already in production and all the values that are currently in that field are integers.

**EDIT 1**

My Model class

```
public class Team extends RealmObject {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;
}
```

my migration after trying Christian's answer

```
if (oldVersion == 6) {
            RealmObjectSchema teamSchema = schema.get("Team");
            teamSchema.addField("temp_id", int.class)
                    .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                        @Override
                        public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                            obj.setInt("temp_id", Integer.valueOf(obj.getString("id")));
                        }
                    })
                    .removeField("id")
                    .renameField("temp_id", "id")
                    .addPrimaryKey("id");
        }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There isn't an one-liner method, but you can follow the same pattern as in our Migration example: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java#L132-L132

```
        schema.get("MyClass")
            .addField("new_key", int.class)
            .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                @Override
                public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                    obj.setInt("new_key", Integer.valueOf(obj.getString("old_key")));
                }
            })
            .removeField("old_key")
            .addPrimaryKey("new_key")
            .renameField("new_key", "old_key");
```

Comment: Is `removePrimaryKey` implicitly applied when using `removeField`?

Comment: I would like to have the name of the old column and new one to be same... Is that possible?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it was a bug we fixed in 1.0.1 https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @Gowtham Yes, that is possible, just rename the field. It is also in our example on the website, but i'll update it here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Christian.... will try it and let you know

Comment: @Christian I am getting this error `Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Primary key not defined for field 'id' in existing Realm file. Add @PrimaryKey.`

Comment: I have edited the question with my class. Please help me with the same.

Comment: I am using Realm 1.0.1 only

Comment: @ChristianMelchior to the rescue. Thanks for this dude.